# How can I use ReSharper to list public methods in a solution which can be converted to private?

Tags: c#, resharper

In my C# winforms project, there are an abundance of methods defined which are internally used only.

e.g.

```
public void AddPrimaryKeyProperty(string primaryKey)
{
    AddProperty(PrimarykeyProperty, primaryKey);
}

public void AddProperty(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    //...
}
```

I'm familiar with the "Find usages" functionality, but would like to be able to generate a list of methods which can be converted to private. In the example above, AddProperty() can be converted to private.

Does such functionality exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resharper will do this for you, but you must turn on Solution-Wide analysis and have all of the projects/assemblies that consume your class in your solution (ie: if there's an assembly that consumes your method but isn't part of the current Visual Studio solution, then ReSharper won't know about it and will say you can make the method private).

For more information about Solution-Wide Analysis, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2017.1/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Code_Inspections.html

Specifically, it provides a list of code inspections that are *only* available when Solution-Wide Analysis is enabled, including `Members and types that can be made internal, private or protected instead of public`

You can then use the various inspection reports (or the "Inspection Options" context window -- see below) to find all instances of this specific code inspection.
[image]

Comment: Solution-Wide analysis was turned-off. It worked after enabling it. Thanks.